# Couldn't Match with Expected Type

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and learning to do some simple recursive functions.  I'm working on a function 'exists' which takes in a value and a tuple.  I'm supposed to return true if the given value is contained in the tuple. Ive looked through other problems like this but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

I created a helper function `existsHelper` that takes in the value and list as parameters and recursively check if the value exists. I keep getting an error stating "`Couldnt match expecting type [t] -> Bool with actual type Bool`".

```
--  exists
exists :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
exists p []     = False
exists p (c:xs) = if existsHelper p c
                  then True
                  else (exists p xs) 


-- existsHelper function
existsHelper p []     = False  
existsHelper p (x:xs) = if p == x
                        then True
                        else existsHelper p xs
```

Some sample inputs/outputs

```
λ> exists 1 []
false
λ> exists 'e' "Hello"
true
λ> exists [4] [[3], [2], [4]]
true
```

Comment: Your `exists` function only has one parameter but the type signature specifies two.

Comment: You also say your function "takes in a tuple" yet there are no tuples in sight in either the type signature or the attempted implementation. I think you are trying to find an implementation for [elem](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) (the function that checks if an element is in a list), which definitely doesn't involve tuples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the func definition went over my head. I made the edits above but still receiving an error "cannot construct infinite type"

Comment: You call `existsHelper p c` but `c` is not a list. You are making it way more complex than you need. The helper already does all the work you want, there's no need for another function.

Comment: @chi For (c:xs), if c is a list and xs are remaining tuples, wouldn't it be needed?

Comment: @Alex, in `c` is not (necessarily) a list there, it is just an element of type `t`. `xs` is a list, of type `[t]`. We know this because `(:)` has type signature `a -> [a] -> [a]` - it takes an element and a list, and returns the result of prepending that element to the list. I have no idea why you are talking about tuples again, I repeat that there are no tuples involved here at all.

Comment: And aside from that as @chi has already said, you've already solved this problem because your `existsHelper` does *exactly* what you want `exists` to do - try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exists function has type:

```
exists :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
```

this defines two arguments - an element of some type implementing the `Eq` typeclass and a list of that element (note: lists and tuples are different things. Tuples are heterogenous collections of a fixed size while lists have arbitrary length where all elements have the same type).

Your `existsHelper` function also has this type and implements your desired behaviour so you can simply rename it:

```
exists :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Bool
exists p [] = False  
exists p (x:xs) = if (p == x) then True else (exists p xs)
```

Comment: You could also write the second line as simply `exists p (x:xs) = p == x || exists p xs`.